# What is causing this format String attack?

Tags: c++, c, string-formatting

Look at this vulnerable snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf(argv[1], "bla");
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it without optimization leads to

```
./test "asd"
asd

./test "asd %s"
asd bla

./test "asd %0\$s"
asd %0$s

./test "asd %45\$s"
asd XDG_VTNR=7 <-- What the...
```

Well, actually it seems like "%(number)\$s" tries to interpret the (number)th argument as a string, looking upside the stack, and I met my environment variables. Is the use of such an format string documented anywhere, especially the use of the curious "\$" ? I couldn't find any references.

Finally, compilation with optimization enabled it leads to:

```
*** invalid %N$ use detected ***
asd zsh: abort      ./test "asd %46\$s"
```

I've never seen such an error before. Where does it come from?

(I'm using Gentoo Linux / GCC 4.8.2 / glibc 2.18)

Comment: I also found this while debugging why the character `X` (rather than the final char in `argv[2]`) was appearing in the output of a program I was testing. It appeared contiguously with argv[2] (just after `argv[2]`'s terminating `NUL` char). `(gdb)p sp1 = argv[2] + 4` => `$11 = 0x7fffffffe4a7  "XDG_VTNR=1"`. So it's apparently in the read-only section.

Comment: Interestingly, what I found for `argv` is that if I check the memory contiguous with `argv[1]` (`argv[1] + strlen(argv[1])`), it is indeed the contents of `argv[2]`, but the contiguous memory for `argv[2]` (the last argument), which is an environment variable `"XDG_VTNR=1"` is not the same as argv[3], which is apparently a null pointer terminating the list. `argv[4]`, *however*, does contain that memory, and continuing to go down after the end of argv reveals a ton of environment variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's [mentioned in the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) like you'd expect. It seems to come from the Single Unix Specification (i.e. not C99).

It's used in internationalization, when you ofteen need to swap around the order of various pieces of information to fit the translation. The number is an argument index:

> One can also specify explicitly which argument is taken, at each place where an argument is required, by writing `"%m$"` instead of `'%'` and `"*m$"` instead of `'*'`, where the decimal integer m denotes the position in the argument list of the desired argument, indexed starting from 1

So in a more sensible program, this:

```
printf("%2$d %1$d", 1, 2);
```

prints

```
2 1
```

It's possible that buiding with optimizations enabled makes the compiler perform more heavy-weight analysis of the code, so that it can "know" more about the actual argument list and generate a better error.

Comment: Well.... Ok. Point taken. Nice behaviour ;-) And what about my error when I enable optimization?

Comment: @rralf: the error is likely coming from your stdlib printf implementation -- it does some sanity checking when it sees a `%N$` format to make sure it's not unreasonable.  As to why it only triggers when optimization is turned on, that's a mystery.